# How can I achieve a limit character in jquery in this situation?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Run the code to see result, it will replace space with '-'. I want to achieve only  one'-' between two text, like 'good-day', but not good----day. Therefore, I want to know how to limit only one between word in jquery.

```js
$('#tag').on("keydown",function(event){
var $input = $('#tag'); 
     $input.val(function(_,v){
return v.replace(/\s+/g,'-');
     });// '-'repace space
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tag" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because when you enter a space it is replaced with `-`, then when you enter another space, (the previous one is already replaced with `-`) so you have `-<space>` now the new space is again replaced with `-` so you get `--`

```js
$('#tag').on("keydown", function(event) {
  $(this).val(function(_, v) {
    return v.replace(/[\s-]+/g, '-');
  }); // '-'repace space
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="tag" />
```